# Cannot reach server from external network when docker is running on the host

Tags: networking, firewall, redhat, docker

I've got two (virtual) servers from an external provider which I can access from my local corporate network via a permanent VPN tunnel. I don't know the details of the network setup, but I can ping both servers and access them via ssh with a local network adress (10.x.y.z). Both servers have quite fresh installs of RHEL 7.2. Let's call them server1 and server2

I've installed docker (from the official rpm repo) on server1, but *as soon as I started the docker deamon, I lost contact with it*. I can log onto server2 and then hop into server1 and there everything seems normal, but *I cannot directly connect to server1 from my network anymore*.

In order to directly connect to server1 again I need to stop docker (which is managed as a systemd service) and reboot server1.

I suspect some kind of conflict with some kind of firewall somewhere, but I don't know how to proceed. So far I have flushed the ip tables on server1 and verified that firewalld is not running, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to include the IP addresses and networks involved.

Comment: Check your default route, docker comes up after the network and can mess with your routing table when it configures it's interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the IP I was coming from when using the VPN tunnel (172.17.127.x) was in the same range the docker0 interface was using (172.17.0.0/16 is the default). That was not the case from the other servers I had tried to ssh from.

In the end to avoid the conflict I simply changed the startup configuration for the docker daemon to use another subnet (192.168.1.5/24) for the docker0 interface and the problem was solved.

```
/usr/bin/dockerd --iptables=false --bip=192.168.1.5/24
```